# Accessing static properties from prototype methods

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

In `class` syntax, we can access the constructor easily:

```js
class MyClass {
  static get STATIC_PROP() {
    return 500;
  }
  getStaticProp() {
    return this.constructor.STATIC_PROP;
  }
}
item = new MyClass();
console.log(item.getStaticProp()); // prints 500, so: cool!!
```

But in `prototype` syntax, it does not seem that easy:

```
MyClass = function() {};
MyClass.STATIC_PROPERTY = 500;
MyClass.prototype = {
  getStaticProp() {
    return this.constructor.STATIC_PROPERTY
  }
}
item2 = new MyClass();
console.log(item2.getStaticProp()); // prints undefined, so: not cool... it should print: 500
```

Can anyone help me to find out how can I achieve what I am doing in the first code, within the paradigm of the second code (meaning `prototype` and not `class`).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I could solved this by adding:

```js
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
```

I guess this is the only way to remain functional while accessing static properties from `prototype` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning a new object to `MyClass.prototype`, you should define a new property on the `MyClass.prototype` object.

change

```
MyClass.prototype = {
  getStaticProp() {
    return this.constructor.STATIC_PROPERTY
  }
}
```

to

```
MyClass.prototype.getStaticProp = function() {
   return this.constructor.STATIC_PROPERTY
}
```

```js
const MyClass = function() {};
MyClass.STATIC_PROPERTY = 500;

MyClass.prototype.getStaticProp = function() {
   return this.constructor.STATIC_PROPERTY
}

const item2 = new MyClass();
console.log(item2.getStaticProp());
```

You could use the name of the constructor function directly to access the static property

```js
const MyClass = function() {};
MyClass.STATIC_PROPERTY = 500;

console.log(MyClass.STATIC_PROPERTY);
```